# Pandas groupby function is not working property inside dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am attempting to use python as a data retrieval tool to get data from a government website and produce an average for each individual day over a 4 day period. The data comes from gauge that takes a data point ever 15 minutes and is then posted online. Because of the website design, my current attempt utilizes beautifulsoup, converts the data into a csv, then the csv file into a df for analysis.

So far, I am able to get the data from the website into a df, but I am not able to get the daily average. The groupby function does not appear to work as the new dataframe is unchanged. Why is groupby not working in this case? Do i need to alter the date column?

[Link to website in question](https://www.usbr.gov/pn-bin/instant.pl?parameter=CHRO%20q&syer=2023&smnth=3&sdy=25&eyer=2023&emnth=4&edy=4&format=2)

code is below:

```
url=https://www.usbr.gov/pn-bin/instant.pl parameter=CHRO%20q&syer=2023&smnth=3&sdy=25&eyer=2023&emnth=4&edy=4&format=2

response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
data=soup.findAll('pre')[1]

stringdata=str(data) #converts data into a string
stringdata=stringdata[53:] #chops off the text at the top of the soupdata
input_data=io.StringIO(stringdata)  #coverts the data into a string

#coverts the data into a csv file
with open ('cherryCreek.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer=csv.writer(file)
    reader=csv.reader(input_data)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)

df=pd.read_csv('cherryCreek.csv', names=['date','cfs'])
df=df.iloc[:-2] #truncates last two rows of text in df
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], utc=True)

df_avg=df.groupby('date').mean()
df_avg.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

check the data type of the second column which is supposed to be numeric.
If the datatype is object then you need to convert the column to numeric datatype using the function astype

Comment: the data type in the second column is numerical - float64